# Accessing inner hidden abstract class to get status updates

Tags: java, android, reflection, abstract

I want to invoke a private method which takes abstract class parameter and that abstract class is hidden (I can not access it directly). I need to get the updates whenever methods of abstract class are invoked by some other class.

Class I am refereeing to is:

```
public class A{

  private void method(AbstractClassA object){ ... }

 // please note below class is hidden. I can not do A.AbstractClassA . I have to access it using reflection unless there is any other way

  public abstract class AbstractClassA {

  //I am interested in getting this int whenever someone else calls the progressUpdate

       public void progressUpdate(int update);
   }
}
```

I am trying to access like this:

```
public class myClass{

    Class<?> abstractClass =  Class.forName("<package>.A$AbstractClassA");
    A a = new A();
    Method someMethod = a.getDeclaredMethod("method", (Class[])null);
    someMethod.setAccessible(true);
    someMethod.invoke(a, <something which I don't know>); //how to pass paramerts here so that I get all callbacks whenever progressUpdate is called by someone else and "update" parameter is changed.


}
```

Comment: How are you creating an instance of an abstract class? you are not supposed to be doing that...

Comment: I want to create concrete class of hidden internal abstract class. How should I do that?

Comment: I think you should extend from `A`, create an instance of `AbstractClassA` using a subclass of it (anonymous subclass if you want, but you can make an inner class that extends from it too), then invoke the private method with reflection.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you give an example please

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SubClassA extends A {
    private SubClassAbstractA subClassA;

    public SubClassA() {
        this.subClassA = new SubClassAbstractA();
    }

    public class SubClassAbstractA extends AbstractA {
        @Override
        public void progressUpdate(int update) {
            SubClassA.this.progressUpdate(update);
        }
    }

    public void progressUpdate(int update) {
        //do things with int
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        Class<?> clazz = A.class;
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(this, subClassA);
    }
}
```